# Listing all the directories that contain a specific file and store them in an array

Tags: shell, scripting, zsh

How to list all the directories that contain a specific file and store them in an array using shell script. I tried the following code but it gave me this error: `ls: **/myFile.txt: No such file or directory`. `myFile.txt` can be any file.

code:

```
folderArray = ($(ls **/myFile.txt | tr -d myFile.txt))
echo folderArray
for folder in ${folderArray[@]}
do
    echo "myFile.txt is present in $folder"
done
```

Comment: The error message you get from `ls` indicates that `**` is not recognized as globbing pattern and it looks for a file actually named `**/myFile.txt`. It could be that the `GLOB` option is unset (Check with `setopt | grep '^noglob$'). Also `tr` works on single characters, so `tr -d abc` would not only remove the strinc 'abc' but all 'a', 'b' and 'c'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to list all the directories that contain `myFile.txt`:

```
find . -type f -name 'myFile.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} dirname {}
```

And to store them in an array:

```
arr=( $(find . -type f -name 'foo.*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} dirname {}) )
```

Comment: although like much of zsh using the find is a more general solution

Answer (score 1):

Use the power of `zsh`:

```
folderArray=($(echo **/myFile.txt(N^/:h)))
```

Flags inside `()` at the end are so called glob modifiers used in file names generation.

- `N`: sets the `NULL_GLOB` option
- `^/`: matches only files, not directories
- `:h`: strips filenames from results, works as `dirname`